# Casper hanging for a long time before waitForSelector gets called

Tags: casperjs

I have a casperjs script that has a bunch of snippets like this:

```
casper.click('.some-class')
casper.waitForSelector(
  '.some-class-on-the-next-page',
  function () { console.log('do stuff') },
  function () { console.log('do timeout stuff') }
)
```

When I run casper in verbose/debug mode, I can see the click get called which triggers a page navigation, but it hangs for a long time before either of my callback functions get called.  The last line I see in the console is:

```
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://some.url/"
```

The pages being navigated to kick off a bunch of JSON requests that are taking 10+ minutes to load.  I'm thinking that [page.resource.requested](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-resource-requested) is the way to filter out these requests and speed up my script which doesn't rely on these JSON resources anyway.

Is there a better approach?  I'm imagining a casper wait* function that can detect a selector as soon as it's available on the page regardless of the status of the page's requested resources.

Comment: If you actually have this in your script then you should see the result immediately when the selector appears in the next page. Can you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of you script so that I could test it?

Comment: The JSON requests run in the page's `onLoad` (or after)? If so, they will be running in parallel with your `waitForSelector`, and it should work as you expect. As Artjom says, it'd be helpful to see more of your script and/or the page being loaded.